# Google maps get position of an marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, algolia

I am adding multiple markers, and what I want to do is on click, get that specific marker position.

However at the moment it does work however it displays lat and lng for the last marker created. How can this be solved so that when I click on the marker it will give me that specific position of that marker.

```
function algolia_search(position) {
  clearOverlays();
var APPLICATION_ID = '75RQSC1OHE';
var SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY = 'f2f1e9bba4d7390fc61523a04685cf12';
var INDEX_NAME = 'businesses';
var PARAMS = { hitsPerPage: 20 };
// Client + Helper initialization
var algolia = algoliasearch(APPLICATION_ID, SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY);
var algoliaHelper = algoliasearchHelper(algolia, INDEX_NAME, PARAMS);
// Map initialization
algoliaHelper.on('result', function(content) {
    renderHits(content);
  var i;
  // Add the markers to the map
  for (i = 0; i < content.hits.length; ++i) {
    var hit = content.hits[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: hit._geoloc.lat, lng: hit._geoloc.lng},
      map: map,
      label: hit._geoloc.slug,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    markers.push(marker);
     marker.addListener('click', function() {
      var destinationLat = marker.getPosition().lat();
      var destinationLng = marker.getPosition().lng();
      console.log(lat);
      console.log(lng);
      console.log(destinationLat);
      console.log(destinationLng);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a listerner on map for click   in event.latLng you have coordinates

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    alert ( 'Lat : '  + event.latLng.lat() + ' Lng : ' + event.latLng.lng())
});
```

do the fact you have already place the marker  on maps  you could use a closure

```
  var addListenerOnPoint = function(actMark){

    actMark.addListener('click', function() {
         alert ( 'Lat : '  + actMark.position.lat() + ' Lng : ' +actMark.position.lng());
    });


  for (i = 0; i < content.hits.length; ++i) {
      var hit = content.hits[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: hit._geoloc.lat, lng: hit._geoloc.lng},
      map: map,
      label: hit._geoloc.slug,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    addListenerOnPoint(marker, 
                  );
    markers.push(marker);

  }
```

Comment: nope that doesn't work still brings me same lat and lng

Comment: .. impossible  ... this listerner  return the coord of the point you click on map ..  could be , you have placed  the code in wrong place..

Comment: well it works when I click on map, but not when I click on the marker

Comment: answer  update with a suggetion for adding a listener for each  marker

Comment: works awesome please not in alert you have missed + after Lng : and closing bracket for alert ;) thanks